Desperately trying to load Kismet on a persistent USB to run on a surface pro 9
I can load the persistent drive with Kismet on a regular laptop, but when I try to run it on a Surface Pro 9, I get the following error: "could not disable real time clock events"

You've highlighted the issue has being hardware specific (it works on another laptop device) and have mentioned no Ubuntu specifics; so we have nothing we can help you with anyway, as your question specifics concentrate on a hardware problem only.
